# How can I take each word from an array alone and test if it fits specific conditions? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function, while-loop, words

I am trying to create a program that reads a sentence from a text file and then prints only the words that do NOT start with a vowel.

So I wrote a program that reads the text file and copies the sentence into an array. Now, I'm struggling with actually testing each word in the array for whether it fits the condition (not starting with a vowel) or not.

So far I can only do that by using the strtok function and using the spaces as delimeters, but that also eliminates the spaces from the sentence, which isn't the desired result.

For example, if the text file contains the following sentence:
An apple a day keeps the doctor away.

The output will be:
daykeepsthedoctor

While the desired output is:
day keeps the doctor

Here's my program:

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int vowelwords();

int main() 
{

    vowelwords();
    return 0;
}

int vowelwords()
{
    FILE *fPtr;
    char text[50];
    fPtr = fopen("TEXT1.txt","r"); //to open file

    if (fPtr == NULL) //Catch error in fopen function
    {
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    fgets(text, 50, fPtr);
    fclose(fPtr);

    char *c;
    c = strtok(text," ");

    while(c!= NULL) 
    {
        if(c[0]=='a'||c[0]=='A'||c[0]=='e'||c[0]=='E'||c[0]=='u'||
           c[0]=='U'||c[0]=='i'||c[0]=='I'||c[0]=='o'||c[0]=='O')
        {
        }

        else  
        {
            printf("%s", c);
        }  

        c = strtok(NULL," ");       
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Why not do `printf("%s ", c);` with an additional space?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have no idea how I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

While printing leave a space in `printf` in function `int vowelwords()` -

```
printf("%s ", c);
          ^ leave a space
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!